# Configuring IPTables to exclude webhost from VPN tunnel

Tags: iptables, vpn

I have a Raspberry Pi running as a server for my webhost. 
Raspberry pi is connected to a VPN service 24/7.

Due to this, I am unable to connect to my webhost using my public IP address issued by my ISP.

> If I were to turn off VPN on my Raspberry Pi, I have no issues
>   connecting to my webserver.

I am using port 8080 for my apache.

How can I re route my traffic so that I am able to access port 8080 using my ISP giving IP?
My Raspberry Pi is on static ip 192.168.1.11 locally.

Eg, If my public ISP is 123.456.789.001, how am I able to access my Raspberry Pi at 123.456.789.001:8080?

**How I start my VPN:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

**VPN Config**

```
client
dev tun2
proto udp
remote 176.126.237.214 25000
remote euro214.vpnbook.com 25000
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
```

**ifconfig**

```
tun2      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.10.0.56  P-t-P:10.10.0.78  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19415 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4242 errors:0 dropped:94 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:26759154 (25.5 MiB)  TX bytes:289187 (282.4 KiB)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is called [Port Forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) - you will need to log into your router (or the device which is assigned your public IP address, if this is a different device) and create a rule which forwards traffic on port 8080 to your Raspberry Pi's IP address. As you haven't given any other detail, I'm unable to give you any exact instructions.

Your VPN configuration also uses the `redirect-gateway` option, which will change the default gateway of the Raspberry Pi (see [docs](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect)). With this option in place, packets will reach your Pi, but will not be able to be passed back to the router. You will need to remove this to keep the Raspberry Pi available to the local LAN.

Comment: Thanks but I know what is port forwarding. Port is already forwarded. It's not working because it's connected to VPN, when I disconnects VPN, it works.

Comment: @Hexark you'll need to add more information about your VPN configuration for me to be able to help you. Type of VPN, what software is being used to connect, etc.

Comment: I have edited the question to give more info

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my answer, you'll need to remove the `redirect gateway` option.

Comment: What is redirect gateway? If i remove what will happen? whats the purpose?

Comment: Check the documentation I linked to - the option changes the default gateway of the Pi to be the remote end of the VPN connection, effectively forcing all traffic down the tunnel.

Comment: Wait, I want to force all traffic down the tunnel. Why do I remove it? I just want 8080 to be accessible from my ISP IP. Im sure its something to do with routing and not just deleting redirect gateway..

Comment: I answered the question - if you force all traffic into the VPN tunnel, how is Apache supposed to respond to the traffic it receives via port forwarding? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I believe it's possible to force only some applications/routes to use the VPN service..

Comment: @Hexark - It's not possible. Routing is an OSI layer 3 service, and applications are OSI level 7. You can either statically route certain **subnets** to use the VPN tunnel, or you can force all **subnets** over the tunnel. Applications are not configurable unless they have specific settings (i.e. Firefox can route traffic at Layer 7 levels via an HTTP proxy, which you may have at the far end of the tunnel).

Comment: A standard use-case of a VPN is "road warriors" accessing corporate networks from the outside world - they dial into the VPN, which can either 1) route **all** traffic from their computer, through the tunnel and out the other side (in this case, all traffic appears to be from the remote location) - or 2) route **some** specific subnets via the VPN (in this case, only traffic addressed to the corporate network will be routed over the tunnel, and the rest will be sent to the LAN's gateway). This is how VPNs work. Anything else will require hackery.

Answer (score 1):

You have `redirect-gateway` enabled, which is telling the VPN client to route all traffic through OpenVPN.  If you only want a specific set of traffic to go through OpenVPN, then set up those routes individually. For example, you could add the following to push all traffic bound for 10.12.34.0/24 through the VPN.

```
(with no redirect-gateway)
route 10.12.34.0 255.255.255.0
```

In reverse, you can direct OpenVPN to exclude a subset of traffic. If you don't want traffic to 123.45.67.0/24 to go through the VPN, then you can include this line:

```
(with redirect-gateway)
route 123.45.67.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
```

Comment: Ahh! Ok, let me try it out!

Comment: So does this mean. I can ensure all my application are going through the tunnel, while allowing me to get to 8080 using my public ip? Or in the first place, Im asking a question that is impossible?

Comment: that depends on how much you can narrow down the intended IP ranges.

Comment: What do you mean intended IP ranges? Erm, I tried route 123.45.67.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway. But i still can't access. Or rather, I should say. How can I exclude apache(port 80, 8080 or what ever port is configured) from going through the tunnel. Basically, I want everything to ultilise the tunnel for privacy. But only my webhost to be excluded.

Comment: In that case you need to look at some iptables wizardry to redirect the traffic.

Comment: yes! iptables! exactly what i needed, but i just dont know how to configure it >.<

Answer (score 0):

Hi seem to have solve my problem by adding a few IPTables, which is as follows.

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.11 table 128 
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.1.1
```

I believe this setting causes all incoming traffic(all ports) to be excluded from VPN Tunnel,  while still ensuring that my outgoing is through the VPN. I'm able to connect to my server now using my public IP, and still able to browse the network using VPN connection.

I have a question though, if I were to torrent, does it mean my ISP can see torrent traffic coming into my IP, because incoming traffic is no longer encrypted?

This is for clarification purpose and not anything about breaking the laws.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to whether your ISP can see the torrent traffic?